# Android CMake project dependency

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake, android-studio-2.2

i currently use CMake for native code with Android Studio.

My project setup is as following:

Module A needs Module B, these dependencies are true for java and native code.

How am i supposed to reference my Module B in the CMake File of my Module A?

Greetings,
Geki

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You said "Module A needs Module B". Does that mean Module B is a project dependency? If so, what does the dependency have to do with the CMake file? CMake file is only for Native. So you have `gradle project...` in your Module A's `build.gradle` and you would have to reference the CMake file in the same Module A's `build.gradle`. If Module B is just a library, it has nothing to do with it

Comment: Your Module A's native code directly calling into your Module B's native code? if that is not case, then on native side, A does not depend on B, so no need to worry.  If you do have code directly calling from A-native to B-native, you would treat module B's native code to be part of module A's native code, and have your module A's cmakelists.txt script to include it -- it would be better to avoid this way. in case your have some code shared by both module A-native and module B-native, maybe create a static lib have them both use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
My Module A directly uses the Module B code natively. So currently i include headers manually in the CMakeLists of Module A and link against the libmoduleb.so that is included in my exploded-aar folder. The problem is that Android Studio has a race condition and so i have to build Module B before i can build Module A (manually) without linker errors.

Also the Module A uses java files of my module B. Those are resolved with compile project(':B').

I don't know how to modify the CMakeLists of A to tell it that it needs the headers and libraries of module B.

Comment: @Gerry I would prefer not to have duplicate code in my IDE. If i fully include CMakeListsB.txt into CmakeListsA.txt i will have duplicate libmoduleb.so files. I would like to keep A and B separated, but link against the build-result of b.

Comment: @Geki, understood your usage model. it is a problem to solve, I do not have have other solution

Comment: @Geki, Did you ever get this figured out?